# Function trigger icheck plugin click

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I am facing some issue Jquery icheck click trigger for example:-
this is my function and what I am trying to do...

```js
function resetfilter() {
  $('.filtercheckbox').each(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (isChecked == true) {
      $(this).trigger('click') /// this case trigger not working with iCheck Jquery Plugins . can you suggest me how to execute trigger function onclick=" resetfilter()" this function
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input class="icheck  filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox" checked value="1">
<input class="icheck  filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox" checked value="2">
<input class="icheck  filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox" checked value="3">
<input class="icheck  filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox" checked value="4">
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-round btn-sm" onclick="resetfilter(this);">Reset</button>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Are you trying to uncheck all the checked checkboxes?

Comment: Your code works just fine

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen when using the iCheck plugin?

Comment: There is a duplicate lurking somewhere in here: https://www.google.nl/search?q=icheck+plugin+trigger

Comment: md sabir you need to create a working example of your issue by adding all js/css files. so that we can actually check what's going on.

Comment: yes but with click trigger. need to more function execute on checkbox false, <input icheck class=" filtercheckbox filter-nn" type="checkbox"  ng-click="filterData();" value="{{res}}">

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen but with click trigger. need to more function execute on checkbox false

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your  `$('.filtercheckbox')` with `$('.filtercheckbox:checked')` and use `$().prop('checked', false)` and those will give you:

```
function resetfilter() {
    $('.filtercheckbox:checked').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
}
```

Comment: but with click trigger. need to more function execute on checkbox false